# Why does Behat fail when running a Mink test to an HTTPS-based login service?

Tags: bdd, behat

In order to test internal IT applications from a user's perspective, I need to establish a Behat background for my scenarios that includes logging in to a cookie-based Single Sign On solution.

This is the bare minimum test to set up logging in a Givens.  Once this succeeds there will of course be more "When"s and "Then"s.

```
Feature: Bouncerize
    In order to log in to internal applications
    As an application user
    I need to be able to use the SSO system

    Scenario: Log in to Bouncer
        Given I am on "https://private_url/login/"
        And I fill in "pass_word" with "a hard to guess password"
        And I fill in "id" with "username"
        And I press "Sign In"
```

When I run this scenario, the first Given fails with the error:

```
  Scenario: Log in to Bouncer                                 # features/bouncer.feature:8
    Given I am on "https://gh.bouncer.login.yahoo.com/login/" # FeatureContext::visit()
      A cookie name is required to generate a field value for this cookie
```

So far, there are no customizations in  `FeatureContext` except that it extends `Behat\Mink\Behat\Context\MinkContext`

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you might've encountered https://github.com/Behat/Mink/issues/161 - I quote from the bugreport:

> This is not a problem with Behat or Goutte, I reported to ZF: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF2-169

However, it's apparently been resolved upstream as well, so things should be working fine now.